# Simulate color transparency

Tags: java, colors, rgb, alpha, argb

I have RGB color value and alpha value. How can I get new RGB value assuming that I have white backgound and alpha is applied?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The formula to be applied to each of the color channels is the following:

```
cr = cf * af + cb * ab * (1 - af)
```

where *cr* is the resulting color of the pixel, *cf* is the foreground color, *cb* the background color, *af* foreground alpha and *ab* background alpha.

Note that often color values are stored already premultiplied by alpha in which case the formula simplifies to

```
cr = cf + cb * (1 - af)
```

See also [alpha composing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing).

Comment: Assume I have red color (ff0000) with alpha 0.5, and the background is white. Trying to get result color: ff0000*0.5 + ffffff*0.5 = ff7fff, but this is not what I expect... http://www.colorhexa.com/ff7fff What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Apply the formula to each color individually (red, green, blue)

Comment: What about the alpha channel of the new color?